# FFMPEG scale video to 720px, add black fields at the top and bottom and output 720x1280 (portrait)

Tags: linux, ffmpeg

How to do that? I need a fast method to make Instagram moments of ready videos without using video editor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method below assumes that the source aspect ratio isn't greater than `720/1280`.

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf scale=720:1280:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=720:1280:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1 out.mp4
```

The `force_original_aspect_ratio` in the scale 'fits' the video within the dimensions specified. The pad then expands the canvas to get the size desired.

Comment: With thanks to https://video.stackexchange.com/a/16686, here is a way to make that same padding white, as well as being another example of how to scale a mobile-originating video (in vertical format) correctly to horizontal as well as adjust the video and audio speed at the same time: `ffmpeg -y -i "mobile_input.mp4" -filter_complex "[0:v]setpts=1.5*PTS,scale=1920:1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1920:1080:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2:white,setsar=1/1,setdar=16/9[v];[0:a]atempo=(1/1.5)[a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" output.mp4` 
More info then the original question... but it may help someone..